# How to fill gap in mesh?

Tags: vertices

[image]

Creating a bridge loop no longer works.

Comment: It looks like you have a hole (triangle) with a thin border around it, am i right guessing that you want to just fill the hole or do you also want to get rid of the thin border?
I may though just see it that way as the object has some thickness, is that hole open inside? maybe a different angle closer view could help me understand.

Comment: There isn't a thin border. I just want to get rid of the hole. And no the hole isn't open inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the fact that the hole is not open inside (comment), it means there are faces connecting the front and back of the hole, you need to delete the faces on the 3 sides of the hole, then in "Edge Mode" select the back side 3 edges and press <kbd>F</kbd> and repeat the same with the 3 edges in the front.

Here visual explanation:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, you genius!